# What's the adjective of "plasma"?

Tags: adjectives, science

What would be the adjective of plasma? I've heard both "plasmatic" and "plasmic", but which one refers to plasma in the medical sense, and which refers to the state of matter?

Comment: [M-W Medical Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/plasmic) states that both adjectives are used in the (single) medical sense. // [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/plasmatic) tacitly restricts the use of 'plasmatic' _to_ this  sense: << **plasmatic**
i

Adjective
(not comparable)

Of or pertaining to (blood) plasma>>

Comment: On the other hand, there are 130 000+ Google hits for "plasmatic" + "ions".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Where did you find that? Google Trends isn't showing me anything.

Comment: To my experience, I would say that "plasmic" can be used in both - actually, three cases : you forgot cell biology, where plasmic is used for the liquid inside the cell - cases, whereas "plasmatic" is only used in the medical sense.

Comment: So my plasma TV should really be called a plasmatic TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both cover both.  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plasmatic

Personally, however, I find plasmic more common.  I live in America.

[Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plasmatic%2Cplasmic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplasmatic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplasmic%3B%2Cc0)  shows that  ***plasmatic*** is slightly more common.

Comment: Hello, Hanry. You've not exactly been welcomed, getting a downvote so promptly. It's possibly because (1) dictionaries tend to give registers / domains in which headwords are used, but don't specify for 'related forms'. And/or (2) you don't quote the relevant entries, merely citing the reference. (I'd admittedly downvote this answer if you had say 8k+ reputation, as I don't believe the reference specifies domain for the adjectives.)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to find a clear answer to your question on Internet. Nevertheless :

I'd use "plasmatic" in a biological context, when talking about [the clear yellowish fluid portion of blood or lymph in which the red blood cells, white blood cells, and platelets are suspended](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plasmatic) as in [these publications](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=%22plasmatic%22&hl=fr&as_sdt=0,5).

For [the gel-like substance enclosed within the cell membrane and the organelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytoplasm), there is use plasmic alone, or "something+plasmic" (e.g. "Sarcoplasmic reticulum" for the reticulum of muscle cells) as in [those publications](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?start=10&q=%22plasmic%22&hl=fr&as_sdt=0,5)

Finally, for the fourth state of matter, you'd use "plasmic", but can't find any strong reference, my guess is that the adjectival form isn't common.

As a side note, I find astonishing how neither "plasmatic" nor "plasmic" are used in huge texts describing the plasma (state of matter).

Comment: One source in the first reference you give (The American Heritage® Stedman's Medical Dictionary) seems to state that 'plasmic' and 'plasmatic' are interchangeable in both blood- and cell-related usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : True enough, but I've read somewhere (can't find the ref) that using plasmatic in the cell-related context is a bit outdated